# How to resolve ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index when using re.findall to extract information

Tags: python, findall

I am trying to use re.findall to extract some information from a very long string.
However I been having ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.
I not sure what I have to correct to make this statement working.
Appreciate if anyone can give me some pointer.

```py
df['Part Number']=re.findall(r"^\D{3}\d{4}\D{2}\d{2}\w",str(df["Path"]))
```

String example is as follows:
`V:\DB\CAPGrind\BEFORE\8_INCHES\WG11_5950302.1_5950302.1_A_314696_SAVE_2019_12_02.csv`

```py
path=r'V:\DB\CAPGrind\BEFORE\8_INCHES'

files=glob.glob(path+"/*.csv")

df=None 

    for i, f in enumerate (files) :
        if i==0:
            df= np.transpose(pd.read_csv(f,delimiter="|",index_col=False))
                df['Path'] =f
                df['Machine No']=re.findall("WG-11",str(df["Path"]))
                df['Process']= re.findall("CAPGrind",str(df["Path"]))

            # Not Working. Will return ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index when running. The regular expression should be correct.
            df['Part Number']=re.findall(r'"^\D{3}\d{4}\D{2}\d{2}\w",str(df["Path"]))
```

Comment: check for `WG11` instead for `WG-11` at this line `df['Machine No']=re.findall("WG-11",str(df["Path"]))`

Comment: @Ratnesh, I having problem with this part 'df['Part Number']=re.findall(r"^\D{3}\d{4}\D{2}\d{2}\w",str(df["Path"]))' ,